# I have problem about creating Again my Html elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with JavaScript when rebuilding the Html elements
When I want to recreate the desired element, the first time an element is created, the second time another element is created, but the third time two elements are created, but I want to create an element in the third time, and this cycle in order To continue

My code:

```js
var option = document.getElementsByClassName("option-text")[0];
var AddOption = document.getElementsByClassName("add-option")[0];

function duplicateOption() {
  return option.cloneNode(true);
}

AddOption.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("option-text")[0].append(duplicateOption());
})
```

```html
<div class="mt-1 row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 option-text">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="OptionText">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm add-option"><small>Add</small></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand you want to duplicate the last option and add it after .

For that you need to select the last option not the first. And use [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

And be sure to evaluate the value of `option` when you click on ADD. otherwise the 'lastoption'  won't be the lastoption after you add 1.

See below. Let me know if that is what you are looking for

```js
var AddOption = document.getElementsByClassName("add-option")[0];
  const options = document.getElementsByClassName("option-text")
  

function duplicateOption(option) {
  return option.cloneNode(true);
}

AddOption.addEventListener('click', function() {

   const option = options[options.length-1];
  option.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', duplicateOption(option));
})
```

```html
<div class="mt-1 row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 option-text">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="OptionText">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm add-option"><small>Add</small></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach would be to attach a click event listener to the body that conditionally does something if the event target has the class that we are interested in eg `.add-option`.

Then we can get the ancestor node '.row' with `closest` to clone before adding it to the document body with `appendChild`.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const {
    target
  } = e
  if (target && target.classList.contains('add-option')) {
    const row = target.closest('.row')
    if (row) {
      const cloned = row.cloneNode(true);
      document.body.appendChild(cloned);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="OptionText">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="add-option">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```